How to publish a Word addin to Microsoft AppSource
I'm trying to push my Word plugin to AppSource:

I followed the documentation and created an account on the Microsoft Partner Program: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish
Onced logged I go to enrollment and then I can only enrol in App and Game Development but not Microsoft 365. It says in order to enable it I need a to relogin with my work account.
Did some googling and read that I need a Microsoft Azure Account with Microsoft Entra ID to login. Created it but was unable to create the entra ID lol.

I tried to join the AI Cloud Partner program but also not able. Can someone explain me the steps on how to publish your Word addin on appsource?

Found the solution by myself. You actually need to use this link here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/developer/appsource/register-microsoft-partner-network. There you need to register for the partner program. It's a different link then provided by the other one. Once registered they create a work account for you.

To be fair Microsoft is makeing this really hard to do with a lot of old documentation still available constantly switching between websites its just anoying
